# Make class selected only if current object in VUE not working

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to make a dynamic class in Vue which triggers only if the selected category matches the current category.

[image]

When user clicks on any category class should change, but it won't change (I don't know what I'm missing)

**In view**

```
    <div :class="{'category-selected': this.selectedCategory === null}" v-on:click="selectCategory(null)">Todos</div>
    <div :class="{'category-selected': this.selectedCategory == category}" v-on:click="selectCategory(category)" v-for="category of filteredCategories" :key="category.id">{{ category.name }}</div>
```

**In vue inspector tools I have a category selected as an object**

[image]

**The selectCategory method**

```
  selectCategory (category) {
      this.selectedCategory = category
  },
```

Any idea if I'm missing something in my conditional to show the class when category selected?

Thank you in advance

Comment: At first don't use `this` in a template and only in code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compare objects by using an unique primitive property like `id` :

```
  :class="{'category-selected': selectedCategory!==null && selectedCategory.id == category.id}"
```